# Browsing a zip file in Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have searched for this answer and can't seem to find the solution, I am using imageen's thumb viewing component "imageenmview" what I would like to do is be able to open a zip file and treat it like a regular folder then populate the thumb viewer component without actualy having to extract the zip file.

I tried to extract one file at a time into a memory stream then load the stream into the thumb viewer but didn't have much luck i guess I am having problems getting my head around the system.zip lib in Delphi and help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: @David, fair enough. I have no access to the System.Zip library since i'm stuck with an older (very old) delphi version. Just checked again and it was added in Delphi XE2, right? If the OP wants to uses this library I guess following link can help (http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/native-zip-file-support-in-delphi-xe2)

Comment: @GuillemVicens The ZIP library was added in XE and it works very nicely

Comment: Thanks for the help but am still having problem, I think I am close here is where I am stumped.

Comment: I have an error in this line "zipfile.Extract(s, picture.SaveToStream(decompstream), false);" the compiler indicates there is no overload version of extract so I am not sure how to extract each file into a tmemorystream I have tried to use just the memory stream "decompstream" and tried to use a tbitmap assigned to my memory stream but not having much luck.

Comment: `System.Zip` doesn't expose any method that will extract zip content to a stream. (You can read the source in `System.Zip.pas`, found in your `$(BDSDIR)\Source\rtl\common` folder.) You might want to look at using a different zip library instead. I'd suggest starting with looking into [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia), the open-source component set from TurboPower. I'm not sure off-hand if it supports what you want, but it's a great package in general, and is much better than the `System.Zip` implementation.

Comment: Just checked (quickly) and `TAbUnzipper` has an `ExtractToStream` method that looks like it will do what you want to do. The docs are available at SF, too; they're a little outdated (the current Abbrevia version is 5.0, the docs are from 3.05), but the general use stuff is in there. You'll need to download the documentation separately from the "Files" page; they're not in the 5.0 download itself.

Comment: Thanks I was curious if system.zip would let me to what I needed, and thanks for the tip on abbrevia I kind of thought I would need to use this lib.